# Reading text file till a certain line in R

Tags: r

I am trying to read data from text file like below and want to create a data frame with information that I want.

```
    junk
junk
------------------------------
Name    number  address
------------------------------
xyz      123    xxxxxx
abc      345    yyyyyy
------------------------------
junk
------------------------------
Name    number  address
------------------------------
bcv     789     zzzzzzz
------------------------------
junk
```

I am trying to create a data frame like below from above text file consolidating all similar information from my file.

```
Name    number  address
xyz      123    xxxxxx
abc      345    yyyyyy
bcv      789    zzzzzzz
```

I am using grep("^Name", input) and then reading lines below that. Please let me know how do I stop reading once I find dotted lines(---) and then continue adding records to data frame when I find "^Name" again in my text document.

Thanks, 
Manjunath

Comment: Could you post the rest of your code? I'm thinking you can do something like (while reading in the lines) "if(!("---" %in% line){do stuff}" this should have the effect of skipping over lines that contain "---". It's hard to say how to do the rest without knowing what your text looks like.